# How do I open a subtab of a certain record within the main tab of another record?

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

I am trying to open up a Call_Log__c object record as a sub-tab under an Account main tab within my service console upon completion of a flow.

This is what I have in the visual force page I'm working on, but unfortunately I didn't create the initial vfp and I'm not the most proficient so I'm trying to figure out how it all works:

```
<apex:form >       
        <apex:actionFunction name="redirect" action="{!redirecttoDetail}" rerender="this">
            <apex:param name="accId" value=""/>
        </apex:actionFunction>
    </apex:form>

    <div class=" slds-grid slds-wrap">
        <div id="flowContainer">
            <script type="text/javascript">
          
            var flowName="xxxxx";
            var statusChange = function (event) {
                if(event.getParam("status") === "FINISHED") {
                    flowName="";
                    // Control what happens when the interview finishes
                    var outputVariables = event.getParam("outputVariables");
                    var key;
                    var interactionLog;
                    var accountId;
                    var goHome;

                    for(key in outputVariables) {
                        if(outputVariables[key].name === "OutputInteractionLog") {
                            interactionLog = outputVariables[key].value;
                        }
                        if(outputVariables[key].name === "OutputAccountId") {
                            accountId = outputVariables[key].value;
                        }
                        if(outputVariables[key].name === "goHome") {
                            goHome = outputVariables[key].value;
                            if(goHome==true){
                                CloseTab();
                            };
                        }
                    }

                    //redirect(accountId);
                    redirect(interactionLog);
                    //sforce.console.openSubtab(accountId, 'https://xxxxx.sandbox.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Call_Log__c/a1t3S000000RrVMQA0', true, 'salesforce', null);
                }
            };
```

And this is what I have within the controller:

```
public PageReference redirecttoDetail() {
    String accId;
    accId = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('accId');
    
    PageReference pg = new PageReference('/' + callLogID);
    //PageReference pg = new PageReference('https://xxxxx.sandbox.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Call_Log__c/' + callLogID + '/view?ws=%2Flightning%2Fr%2FAccount%2F' + accId + '%2Fview');
    pg.setRedirect(true);
    return pg;                           
}
```

I tried hard coding the URL just to test and that kinda worked but not really. I can easily open either the account record or the call log record as a main tab with no problem so I'm getting the right account ID and call log ID values, but I just cannot figure out how to open the call log record as a subtab of the account record main tab. (and the callLogID variable has the right ID, it is just in another part of the code I didn't include)

Does anyone know how I can properly use the PageReference or the openSubTab() method or any other method?